# Ошибка: RenderBox was not laid out при добавлении TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

Совсем недавно я начал  изучать программирование на языке flutter и при создании приложения в Android studio я получаю ошибку:

> RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderDecoration#c6cd3 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно? Код программы:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewsBoxFavourit extends StatefulWidget {
  final int _num;
NewsBoxFavourit(this._num);
@override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState();
}
class MyFormState extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container( child : new Column(children: <Widget>  [  new Text('qwqwqwqeee'),
        Expanded(child:new TextFormField() )

    ]));
  }
}

class NewsBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _title;
  final String _text;
  String _imageurl;
  int _num;

  NewsBox(this._title, this._text, {String imageurl, int num = 0,}) {
    _imageurl = imageurl;
    _num = num;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_imageurl != null && _imageurl != '') return new Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 100.0,
        child: new Row(children: [
          new Image.network(_imageurl, width: 100.0, height: 100.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          new Expanded(child: new Container(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child: new Column(children: [
            new Text(_title,  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
            new Expanded(child:new Text(_text, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,))
          ]
          ))
          ), new NewsBoxFavourit(_num,)
        ])
    );

    return new Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 100.0,
        child: new Row(children: [
          new Expanded(child: new Container(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child: new Column(children: [
            new Text(_title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
            new Expanded(child:new Text(_text, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,))
          ]
          ))
          ),  new NewsBoxFavourit(_num,)
        ])
    );
  }
}

void main() =>  runApp(
new MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: new Scaffold(
appBar: new AppBar(),
body: new NewsBox('Первый день', '''Бег''',
imageurl: 'https://img.rl0.ru/0e5dfa5a89802f6ae40eea1312ee89c0/c615x400i/https/news.rambler.ru/img/2019/01/25160023.223341.8124.jpeg', num: 0),
)
)

);
```

В программу пытаюсь добавить TextForm или  TextFormField, какая
в них разница? Как их правильно добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно используете [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), он заполняет `child'ом` все доступное свободное пространство в [Flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) виджетах.

```
class MyFormState extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('qwqwqwqeee'),
          TextFormField(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Отличие [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) от [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) в том что, [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) может интегрироваться в [Form](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html), который позволяет работать с несколькими [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) полями одновременно через один [key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html).

---

P.S.:

- ключевое слово `new` устарело, его можно не писать
- в `StatelessWidget` не должно быть полей класса (только `final` или `const`), т.к. он `@immutable`
- `'''Text'''` используют для multi-line text

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @DimaКлушин если ответ вам подошел его можно отметить "галкой" как правильный (под стрелочками).